# ...the first verse of her poem “America the Beautiful"... VS ...the first verse of her poem, “America the Beautiful,"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> Bates composed the first verse of her poem “America the Beautiful" while standing atop Pikes Peak. (From ACT)

In this case, why can't I count "America the Beautiful" as parenthesis and add two comma around it accordingly? As following:

> Bates composed the first verse of her poem, “America the Beautiful," while standing atop Pikes Peak.

Comment: Look up relative clauses

Answer (score -1):

You can't count quote marks as parenthesis, in that sense, because that's not how they are being used - rather they are being used for purely stylistic reasons, to show that *America the Beautiful* is a title.

In many publications, the same effect would be achieved by underlining, or italicising, where it would be far clearer that the styling has no grammatical effect.

Comment: I may have not expressed it explicitly, but what I mean is considering "America the Beautiful" this phrase as a parenthesis and adding two commas that symbolize the parenthesis, instead of looking the quotation mark as parenthesis. Hope I make it clear now.

Comment: But I said quite clearly that you should NOT treat it as parenthesis, rather you should mostly treat the title as a single object, so even one comma would be unnecessary. You could use brackets either side if you wanted to, but again no need for commas.

Answer (score -1):

When you enclose information in parenthetical punctuation (whether commas, dashes, or actual parentheses) you are saying that the information is superfluous to to meaning of the sentence. Whatever the parenthetical clause is can be removed entirely, and the sentence will still be correct in every way. (Notice how I did that in the first sentence of this paragraph!)

In this case, when you remove the title and write

> Bates composed the first verse of her poem while standing atop Pikes Peak.

you are implying that she wrote *only one* poem, so the identifier "her poem" is sufficient to uniquely identify it with no further introduction. **This is not correct!** Bates wrote many poems, so "her poem" on its own is not enough information. So in this case you cannot treat the name of the poem as a parenthetical aside, because its presence in the sentence is **required** rather than **additional** identifying information. In other words, the complete identifier is "her poem 'America the Beautiful'" and the title is an integral part of that identifier, because it needs to clarify *which* of her poems we are talking about.

It is acceptable to use this parenthetical construction if the title of the poem is not required to uniquely identify it in context:

> Bates and Key have competing claims to "the most famous poem in America." Bates composed the first verse of her poem[, "America the Beautiful,"] while standing atop Pikes Peak; Key penned his lines after observing the Battle of Baltimore from Chesapeake Bay.

In this case the only thing the phrase "her poem" needs to do is distinguish *Bates' poem which may be the most famous* from *Key's poem which may be the most famous*; it does not need to distinguish *Bates' poem which may be the most famous* from *all of Bates' poems*. So the actual title of the poem is not needed; "her poem" and "his lines" are clear enough on their own. You can add the title of the poem as a parenthetical phrase.

---

Borrowing a concept from engineering design and drafting, we can say that the identifier "her poem" may be **overdefined**, **underdefined**, or **properly defined**. Take the following examples:

> 1. Bates composed her poem...
> 2. Bates composed her poem "America the Beautiful"...
> 3. Bates composed her poem, "America the Beautiful,"...
> 4. Bates composed her most famous poem...
> 5. Bates composed her most-famous poem "America the Beautiful"...
> 6. Bates composed her most famous poem, "America the Beautiful,"...

In Sentence 1 the poem in question is **underdefined** because there is not enough information; we cannot identify which poem, out of all her poems, the sentence is talking about. Sentence 3 is the same, because the parenthetical phrase may be removed and we are left with Sentence 1 again. Both these sentences are incorrect.

In Sentence 5 the poem is **overdefined**. The poem in question may be defined as *her most famous one* (a superlative, which identifies only one out of all her poems) or it may be *"America the Beautiful"* (a title, which again identifies only one out of all her poems). This is an error because it could be the case that "America the Beautiful" is not her most famous poem! Then there would be a conflict between the two definitions.

Sentences 2, 4, and 6 are all correct. In each of these sentences the poem under discussion is described exactly once: in Sentence 2 by using the title and in Sentence 4 by using a superlative adjective. Sentence 6, because of the parenthetical phrase, is parsed the same way as Sentence 4.

---

The upshot is that it is either **correct** or **incorrect** to use the commas around the poem's title depending on the context, both within the sentence and within the larger paragraph.